# C to Swift bitwise operations

Tags: c, swift, bitwise-operators

I have these functions in C (from Cactus Kev's poker evaluator):

```
unsigned find_fast(unsigned u)
{
    unsigned a, b, r;
    u += 0xe91aaa35;
    u ^= u >> 16;
    u += u << 8;
    u ^= u >> 4;
    b  = (u >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    a  = (u + (u << 2)) >> 19;
    r  = a ^ hash_adjust[b];
    return r;
}

int eval_5hand_fast(int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int c5)
{
    int q = (c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5) >> 16;
    short s;
    if (c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & 0xf000)
        return flushes[q]; 
    if ((s = unique5[q]))
        return s;          
    return hash_values[find_fast((c1 & 0xff) * (c2 & 0xff) * (c3 & 0xff) * (c4 & 0xff) * (c5 & 0xff))];
}
```

and would like to convert them over to Swift:

```
func eval_5hand_fast(c1: Int, c2: Int, c3: Int, c4: Int, c5: Int) -> Int {

    var q: Int = (c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5) >> 16
    var s: Int8
    if c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & 0xf000 {
        return flushes[q]
    }
    if (s = unique5[q]) {
        return s
    }
    return hash_values[find_fast((c1 & 0xff) * (c2 & 0xff) * (c3 & 0xff) * (c4 & 0xff) * (c5 & 0xff))]
}

func find_fast(u: UInt) -> UInt {
    var a, b, r: UInt
    u += 0xe91aaa35
    u ^= u >> 16
    u += u << 8
    u ^= u >> 4
    b  = (u >> 8) & 0x1ff
    a  = (u + (u << 2)) >> 19
    r  = a ^ hash_adjust[b]
    return r;
}
```

I am just learning Swift and haven't really done much with bitwise operations, so bear with me.  I've tried to fix these on my own, to no avail.  The errors I am getting with Swift include:

1. ```
   if c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & 0xf000
   // ERROR: Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'
   ```
2. ```
   if (s = unique5[q])
   // ERROR: Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'
   ```
3. ```
   return hash_values[find_fast((c1 & 0xff) * (c2 & 0xff) * (c3 & 0xff) * (c4 & 0xff) * (c5 & 0xff))]
   // ERROR: Cannot find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments
   ```
4. ```
   u += 0xe91aaa35
   // ERROR: Cannot invoke '+=' with an argument list of type '(UInt, IntegerLiteralConvertible)'
   ```
5. ```
   u ^= u >> 16
   // ERROR: Cannot invoke '>>' with an argument list of type '(UInt, $T5)'
   ```
6. ```
   u += u << 8
   // ERROR: Cannot invoke '+=' with an argument list of type '(UInt, $T5)'
   ```
7. ```
   u ^= u >> 4
   // ERROR: Cannot invoke '>>' with an argument list of type '(UInt, $T5)'
   ```

I get the first error (that it is not a bool), however I'm not sure how to resolve it because I'm not totally sure what the C version is asking, since I am not too familiar with working with bits and masks. The other errors I really don't know what to do with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to integers, anything that is not 0 is considered `true` in C. Swift requires a boolean value so you have to add `!= 0`. For example:

```
C:     if c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & 0xf000
Swift: if c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & 0xf000 != 0

C:     if (s = unique5[q])
Swift: if let s = unique5[q] where s != 0
```

Try this:

```
func eval_5hand_fast(c1: Int, c2: Int, c3: Int, c4: Int, c5: Int) -> Int {

    var q: Int = (c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5) >> 16
    var s: Int8
    if c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & 0xf000 != 0 {
        return flushes[q]
    }
    if let s = unique5[q] where s != 0 {
        return s
    }
    return hash_values[find_fast((c1 & 0xff) * (c2 & 0xff) * (c3 & 0xff) * (c4 & 0xff) * (c5 & 0xff))]
}

func find_fast(var u: UInt) -> UInt {
    var a, b, r: UInt
    u += 0xe91aaa35
    u ^= u >> 16
    u += u << 8
    u ^= u >> 4
    b  = (u >> 8) & 0x1ff
    a  = (u + (u << 2)) >> 19
    r  = a ^ hash_adjust[b]
    return r;
}
```

Comment: First one is good, and thanks for the explanation.  The second one I just set s = unique5[q] before the if statement, then checked if s != 0.

Comment: I have resolved the "overload" error as well, but I can't seem to do anything with the bitwise operation errors in the find_fast function.  I'm guessing some sort of type casting is necessary?

Comment: It seems 'u' is a constant, and changing this made the errors go away.